# NHibernate.MappingException when submit button click

Tags: c#

I have a CommissionAgent.cs class for nHibernate

```
public class CommissionAgent
{
    private int id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    private string commissionAgentName { get; set; }

    public virtual string CommissionAgentName
    {
        get { return commissionAgentName; }
        set { commissionAgentName = value; }
    }
    private string commissionAgentCode { get; set; }


}
```

Here is the nHibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="DSEBO.Data" assembly="DSEBO.Data ">
        <class name="CommissionAgent" table="CommissionAgent">
```

Here is my function to communicate with nHibernate

```cs
string errMsg = "";
//try
{
    ISession session = NHibernateProcessor.GetCurrentSession();
    ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
    CommissionAgent comissionAgent = new CommissionAgent();
    comissionAgent.CommissionAgentName = CommissionAgentName;
    comissionAgent.CommissionAgentCode = CommissionAgentCode;
    comissionAgent.Address = address;
    comissionAgent.ContectNumber = ContectNumber;
    comissionAgent.NID = "NID Test";
    comissionAgent.AccNo = AccNo;
    comissionAgent.Routing = Routing;
    comissionAgent.BankName = BankName;              
    session.Save(comissionAgent);
    try
    {
        tx.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        tx.Rollback();
        tx.Dispose();
        errMsg = "Error in Adding Trader Table for Trader Code:" + CommissionAgentCode;
    }
    //tx.Commit();
    NHibernateProcessor.CloseSession();
}
          

I am getting an exception and data cannot assign the value to the class object and cannot pass the value to the database.
```

Comment: What exception did you get, exactly? Post all the details of it, including the message. Also, post the mapping file.

Comment: An exception of type 'NHibernate.MappingException' occurred in NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No persister for: DSEBO.Data.Commons.CommissionAgent

Comment: "No persister for....." means that no mapping for that class exists. Check that the XML maping file are included as embeeded resources. If the problem continues, post the full mapping so we can see what's happening.